# Asking for user input until end of the string - NO ENTER

Tags: c

I have a bit of code that asks the user for their input (letter) for as many times as the word has letters.

I am not sure why but it is counting the enter for everytime the user inputs the letter and therefore the program stops before the amount of chars existent in the word.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void Game(char *word){
    char letter[2];
    char asterisk = '*';
    char result[strlen(word)];
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(word); j++)
    {
      fgets(letter, sizeof(letter), stdin);
      letter[strcspn(letter, "\n")] = 0;
        if(word[j] == letter[0]){
              strcat(&result[j], &letter[0]);
            } else{
              strcat(&result[j], &asterisk);
           }
    }
}

int main()
{
 char *word="test";
 Game(word);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result. But for starters `strcat(&result[i], &letter[0]);` is wrong. The first arg to `strcat` must always point to a NUL terminated string. But the `result` array is uninitialised. Need at least `result[0]=0` at the top.  But I'm not sure why you are using `i` as the index as `strcat` should be given the start of the string.

Comment: sorry it was a copy code and paste error, I have given the exact input. Asks the user for a letter for as many times as the word has letters.

Comment: The `letter` array is not big enough.

Comment: the letter is 1 + 1 = 1 for the actual letter, another for the enter. How big should it be?

Comment: You need room for the letter, the newline, and the NUL terminator (which is a zero byte that must be at the end of all C strings).